# Can't get image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I've checked several tutorials and from what I can tell my code is correct, but at the end I don't get the image.  I don't get any error, but the image on the screen I'm trying to set is still blank.

Here's my header file

```
@interface homeViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *photoButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

- (IBAction)setPhoto;

@end
```

And here's the related methods

```
- (IBAction)setPhoto 
{
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imgPicker.delegate=self;
    self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.showsCameraControls=YES;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
{ 
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    self.avatarImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.avatarImage.image = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I place a breakpoint here: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
I see that the image variable has a value, but the self.avatarImage has a 0x00000000

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887457/uiimageview-does-not-show-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified `allowsEditing = NO` you need to use the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` info key.

Note: it may be that 'EditedImage' defaults to 'OriginalImage' if no editing occurs.  In that case your 'image' variable will be valid and the display of the UIImageView in self.avatarView will be the culprit.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, both ways end with no image showing.

Comment: No image showing or a NIL value in 'image'?  Add 'NSAssert (image, @"No image");' after the assignment to 'image'.

Comment: I've updated it to show the current code.  The UIImageView seems to be null, but the image that I get seems to be good.  I'm initializing the UIImageView so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: You aren't adding the UIImageView to the screen. You shouldn't be initialized it there, you should be initializing it somewhere like viewDidLoad (and adding it as a subview of some view), then accessing it in the delegate method.

Comment: Doesn't your UI (Storyboard, NIB) already have the avatarImage allocated, inited with a default value, and positioned within its superview?  It should be.  Then just self.avatarImage.image = image with a redisplay will show the selected image.

Comment: That was it, my initializing it again caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong delegate method. Use

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

The delegate method you are using was deprecated in iOS 3.0.

Comment: I changed the delegate method to the one you showed and edited my question, but I still get no image at the end.

Comment: Just for check, do you have the Location services enabled for your app?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check that?

Comment: Is the delegate method getting called though? And location isn't an issue, that is only an issue if you are using lower-level technologies (namely ALAssetLibrary).

Comment: I've updated the question with my code again, the delegate gets called, and I have a value for the image variable, but the UIImageView avatarImage has a value of 0x00000000.

Comment: You aren't using the UIImageView correctly. See my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Have to appear before using the info dictionary.