# How to upload an image in image view +iphone

Tags: iphone

I am a new iphone developer. How can i  upload an image in Image view  which is taken from camera and from photo library.

Thanks to all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImageView does not show Image from UIImagePickerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887457/uiimageview-does-not-show-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Show us the code you have where you have the image that you want to upload...

Comment: bro, even if you are a new iphone developer, you should research  various forums b4 posting any ques cuz that might b a repeation and you might easily avail the answers over the internet. One suggestion though, always refer to apple's documentation before starting your internet reseach cuz apple docs contains everything and if u r unable to understad that , then search the internet. If u r able to find answers in bits and pieces, try structuring and writing the code acc 2 ur own needs n after doing all dese things, nothing works out, then post ur ERRORS along with ur EFFORTS on forums like SO.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
- (IBAction)m_CtrlBtn_SelectImage_click:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) 
    {
        // Set source to the Photo Library
        imgPicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;// imgPicker is a  UIImagePickerController object;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
        {
            UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
            self.popoverController = popover;   
            [popover release];
            // popoverController.delegate = self;
            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 480) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            [imgPicker release]; 
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
        }
    }

}  
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo { 
    m_ImgVw_SelectedImage.image=img;
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];
    picker.delegate=nil;
}
```